# How to connect XAMPP to existing MySQL

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have just installed XAMPP, but in the installation process I unticked MySQL because I already have a previous version on my computer. A couple of months ago I installed MySQL with Workbench and I've been using it, and I want to keep all the databases I have. So, please as simple as possible, given that the service MySQL is currently completely disabled in the XAMPP control panel as I didn't install it with the installer and I can't either start it or stop it (the service), how can I connect the MySQL I already have to XAMPP, so it recognizes it and I can start it from the panel?

Comment: You can manage your own mysql instance via stamdard service / daemon manager utilities.

Comment: @Shadow Never heard of that before. Where can I find it and what do you mean by managing? I'm currently trying to install WordPress and I need the existing MySQL password for XAMPP, but I still don't know how to connect it.

Comment: Xampp does not need tour mysql isername and password. Wordpress does. The two are completely diffferent.

Comment: @Shadow ok, forget the WordPress part, I just want XAMPP to recognize the already installed MySQL, and I didn't understand your first comment, could you please explain it to me a little more clearly?

Comment: Not sure where the config for MySQL is located for XAMPP control panel, but it might be simpler to export your existing databases, re-install XAMPP with MySQL and then import your databases (if the volume isn't huge).

Comment: Why does it matter wether xampp recognises your mysql instance? You can manage it outside of xampp just as fine.